# How to use multiple counts in where clause to compare data of a table in sql?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, relational-database

I want to compare data of a table with its other records. The count of rows with a specific condition has to match the count of rows without the where clause but on the same grouping.

Below is the table

```
-------------
id  name    time    status  
1   John    10      C   
2   Alex    10      R   
3   Dan     10      C   
4   Tim     11      C
5   Tom     11      C
```

Output should be time = 11 as the count for grouping on time column is different when a where clause is added on status = 'C'

```
SELECT q1.time 
FROM   (SELECT time, 
           Count(id) 
    FROM   table 
    GROUP  BY time) AS q1 
   INNER JOIN (SELECT time, 
                      Count(id) 
               FROM   table 
               WHERE  status = 'C' 
               GROUP  BY time) AS q2 
           ON q1.time = q2.time 
 WHERE  q1.count = q2.count
```

This is giving the desired output but is there a better and efficient way to get the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this :

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.time = t.time and t1.status <> 'C');
```

However you can do :

```
select time
from table t
group by time
having sum (case when status <> 'c' then 1 else 0 end ) = 0;
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I went with the second approach. Added 'end' to the case statement. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want the times where the rows all satisfy the `where` clause, then in Postgres, you can express this as:

```
select time
from t
group by time
having count(*) = count(*) filter (where status = 'C');
```